# Extra '\' is inserting into quartz tables bytea column by using npgSQL and PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, quartz.net

When inserting data into PostgreSQL (PG) database (version 11), from a WPF application (C# and nhibernate) using Npgsql v1.0.0/4.1.5 provider, data is getting saved in an incorrect format in the ‘bytea’ type column of the PG database. For troubleshooting purpose, just to see what data is getting inserted, we converted the bytea column to text type, and we observed that there are additional double back slashes that are getting introduced in within data which we do not want. We want to identify the root cause of this incorrect format that is being inserted and how to correct it.

Error1: Couldn't retrieve job: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 5C-30-30-30-31-30-30-30-30-30-30-66-66-66-66-66-66 ...
Error2: Couldn't retrieve job: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

Support Needed: need help in identifying the problematic dll or pinpoint the dependency issue and to get the Quartz implementation working with minor changes to the application.

Components used in the application:

1. Castle.windsor 2.5.2
2. Dotconnect for PostgreSQL
3. Quartz 1.0.3
4. WPF
5. Npgsql 4.1.5
6. .Net Framework 4.6.1
7. PostgreSQL 11

Comment: Wow that's a reaaally old version of Quartz - but I guess you can't upgrade easily. You should at least make sure that you are using the postgre setup to communicate:

`properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.PostgreSQLDelegate, Quartz";`

Comment: Hi, We have tried the above thing and after that also its not working.